# How to check GPU availability in GKE?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

In GKE, I have created multiple clusters with 1 node each, with each node having 1 GPU. These clusters are in different regions. I have deployed my GPU application with kserve on each node (with knative providing scale to 0 capabilities for the nodes). I am using `MultiClusterIngress` for handling the traffic between the clusters.

In `MultiClusterIngress`, I use `BackendConfig` to specify the health check parameters of my application like the readiness endpoint and its frequency. But, the issue is that this health check will always keep the node up even when no actual traffic is coming in. This implies that the GPUs will be always available (as they would not get autoscaled to 0) and hence, I would incur the cost of the GPUs, which defeats the purpose of scale to 0.

I need this health check as I want to ensure that if a GPU is available in a node, only then send the client request to this cluster. Also, sometimes it has happened that GPU is unavailable in a region.

So how can I go about solving this issue of minimising GPU cost? Is there some way for me to cheaply do health check of the GPUs? Or is there some different approach to solving my use case?